# show custom django form error in template

Tags: python, django

I am writing a view to send a password reset email to users. I am checking if the email entered by the user is registered by using the clean method in the forms.py, this is working correctly although I can not get the custom error message to display in the django template.

views.py

```
def send_forgotten_password_email(request):
    heading = 'Reset Password'
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ForgottenPasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            email = form.cleaned_data['email']

    form = ForgottenPasswordForm()

    return render(request,'authentication/forms/forgotten_password.html',{
        'form':form,
        'heading':heading,
        })
```

forms.py

```
class ForgottenPasswordForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.CharField(
        label='Email:',
        widget= forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter email'})
        )

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        email = get_object_or_none(User,email=email)
        if not email:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email not found.")
        return email
```

template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} Forgotten Password {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{heading}}</h4>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    {{form.non_field_errors}}
                    {{form.errors}}
                    {{forms.errors}}
                    {{form.email.errors}}
                </div>
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                  <div class="form-group">

                    <label>{{form.email.label}}</label>
                        {{form.email}}
                  </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to move your empty initial form before if statement:

```
# Added this
form = ForgottenPasswordForm()
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = ForgottenPasswordForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        email = form.cleaned_data['email']

# Remove this line
# form = ForgottenPasswordForm()
```